# How to predefine object with element as an array <string> type?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object, and i need to define in this object sub element, which will be as an array.
But how do i define it's type?
Without type definition it throws error.

> Implicitly has any[]

```
let someObject = {
  somePropety: {
    A : 0,
    B : 0,
    C : []<string>,
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how to asign `C` element an array of string type ?

Comment: Is this TypeScript?

Comment: Yes it's TypeScript

Comment: Add the tag then so the right people can come take a look

Comment: "*Without type definition it throws error.*" - what error?

Comment: Implicitly has any[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for

```
let someObject = {
  someProperty: {
    A: 0,
    B: 0,
    C: [] as string[],
  },
};
```

Alternatively, you can declare the type of the entire `someObject` variable (see @wooooooo's or @ksav's answers for that) instead of using a type assertion on the empty array literal.

Comment: Yes, this is just what i was looking for.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `string[]`. However, it doesn't look like your example is a type definition?

I would write it like this:

```
let someObject: { somePropety: { A: number; B: number; C: string[] } } = {
        somePropety: {
          A: 0,
          B: 0,
          C: []
        }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to define C as an array of strings, you can do:

```
C: string[];
```

or using a generic array type:

```
C: Array<string>
```

You can find more detail on TypeScript basic types [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html)

Comment: Thank you for unswer, i also wanned to do this but it says.
'string' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface for your object, so that you can explicitly type it.

```
interface MyObject {
    somePropety: {
        A: number
        B: number
        C: string[]
    }
}

let someObject: MyObject = {
  somePropety: {
    A : 0,
    B : 0,
    C : ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  }
}
```